# how to disable the web cache when downloading artifacts?

Tags: sbt, ivy

My work's web cache sometimes caches bad versions of jars from maven central. In order to get the correct version, I need to specifically request the `--no-cache` version (e.g. with `wget`).

However, there does not appear to be obvious way to tell `sbt`/`ivy` not to use the web cache... is this possible and if so how do I do it?

This is happening too often for a manual intervention to be scalable.

Comment: no, this is **NOT** about Ivy's cache, this is about the HTTP cache at the networking layer.

Comment: Oh.... Sorry, retracted my close vote. I did some quick digging and found the following link which might describe your root cause. Are you using squid? The work-around sounds extreme (patching ivy).   http://markmail.org/message/vzqk4upnac5rjzlu. Found an additional reference to the same problem in Gradle. They appear ot have fixed it there: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2007. I think you should raise an ivy JIRA issue on this one

Comment: dodgy corporate proxy

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `~/.sbt/0.13/proxy.sbt` (insert proxy address in place of localhost):

```
val WorkaroundShittyProxy = {
  new java.net.URL("http://127.0.0.1/").openConnection().setDefaultUseCaches(false)
}
```